# Java Android - Defining Imports

Tags: java, android, import

I have following problem:
I do have a class, common.java, which will be used by an Android application but also by a Java application.
This class imports an android specific class (android.*).

If I want to build the Java application it does throw the error of a not existing import, of course. 
Programmatically I do all my Android specific stuff in an if clause:

```
if (System.getProperty("java.vm.name").equalsIgnoreCase("Dalvik")) {
  //Android specific stuff
}
```

So: Is there a way, that I can import the Android classes also only if i'm building the android app? Like an if clause around the imports?

```
if(System.getProperty("java.vm.name").equalsIgnoreCase("Dalvik")) {
   import ...
   import ...
}
```

Hopefully my problem is clear. Thanks!!

Comment: consider preprocessing of your code.

Comment: `If I want to build the Java application it does throw the error of a not existing import, of course. ` Remove the offending imports, of course.

Comment: I'd restructure your code so this can't happen, and doesn't require pre-processing. E.g., your Android code imports your common library and extends it, etc.

Comment: I don't want to remove them, because I use them in the Android classes as well... so I have to rewrite the imports all the time I switch between Android and Java. I take a look into preprocessing and think about extending it like Dave said. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to splitt common into portable and os-specific code like this:

```
// has no android or j2se specific code
public class common {
    public void someCommonfunction() {...someOsSpecificcode(); ...}
    protected abstract void someOsSpecificcode();
}

// has android specific code
public class commonAndroid extends common {
    protected void someOsSpecificcode() { /* android specific implementation */ }
}

// has j2se specific code
public class commonJ2se extends common {
    protected void someOsSpecificcode() { /* j2se specific implementation */ }
}
```